# Generate md5 or sha1 hash across windows & linux system in php

Tags: php, md5, sha1

I m trying to generate a signature using md5 or sha1 hash on a linux system. This signature will be tested across a windows system to ensure it authenticates.

What i find is both hash generated using same parameters are different.

Please help how i can generate a common hash on both system for authentication.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. Both md5 and sha1 are defined in a platform-independent way, so they should behave identically across all platforms.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to compute hashes from strings with different encodings?

Comment: Or the string is multi-line so you get different bytes for a newline.

Comment: As Nick pointed out, it may be because of differences in end-of-line sequences (LF vs CR-LF). Also, if you are using command line utilities that compute the hash for a file, note that files containing even a single line may contain an EOL.

Comment: Thanx Guys, It was string encoding. Thanx peter

Answer (score 0):

Sha1 and also MD5 are platform-independent, so if the hash is diffrent form each other, you do not have the same data on each system. Check your encoding and your end-of-line sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CertUtil -hashfile <file> MD5` in windows and `md5sum <file>` in linux

It's the same function, but take care about the encoding, specially about CR vs CR-LF.

Linux and Windows has different ways to encode the "\n"

This can be a problem if you are trying to compute the md5 of a text file, such as a json file.

Comment: they did not return same for a file present on linux and windows
but when used `md5sum` from git bin dir on windows and default of linux, it gave same key